# Find critical Value

Tags: probability, statistics

A Basketball scout randomly selected 144 players and timed how long each player took to perform a certain drill.The times in this sample were distributed with a mean of 8 minutes. The population standard deviation was known to be 3 mintes.

A. Find the critical value for a 95% confidence interval for the population mean of drill times?

B. Using a 95% confidence interval, estimate the population mean of drill times?

my solution is

The random variable in question is the time taken to complete the drill by an individual (randomly selected) player. Assuming this random variable, which I'll denote X, is normally distribute. Let M denote the (unknown) population mean. Let m denote the population mean (for this case, 8).

We construct a new variable,

Z = (M - m) / [3 / sqrt(144)] = = 4 (M - m)

which then obeys the standard normal distribution.

We are looking for a value z such that P(-z < Z < z) = 0.95. To find this value using the table, we first use the symmetry of the standard normal distribution about its (zero) mean to write:

0.95 = P(-z < Z < z) = 2 P(0 < Z < z) = 2 [P(Z < z) - P(Z <= 0)] = 2 [P(Z < z) - 0.5] = 2 P(Z

so P(Z < z) = 1.95 / 2 = 0.9750, which gives us the estimate z = 1.96.

Therefore, the confidence interval for M is [m - z/4, m + z/4] = [7.51, 8.49].

B. Not sure how to do the said "estimate." If we take the midpoint of the confidence interval as the estimate, we end up with M = m. A more pessimistic estimate would be closer to 7.51 than to 8.49

Comment: The reasonable estimate is $8$. If we want to give an **interval**, it is the one you computed in your answer to the first question.

Comment: Sir can you help me finding out the population mean of drill times?  or can u suggest something in my answer? a more comprehensive form please

Comment: I wrote the answer above. If we want to make a point estimate, our estimate for the population mean is $8$. If we want to give an interval estimate, a symmetric interval is $[7.51,8.49]$.